# "Mapping keys are not allowed here" when I use '?' character in the yaml file. How I could make that the program to can use the '?' character?

Tags: java, yaml

```
folder:
  name: folderA
  files:
  - name: fileA
  folders:
  - name: ?
    files:
    - name: fileB
```

I use yaml with Java and I have an error in Eclipse at the line with `- name: fileA`. Does exist a way in that I could use '?' in a yaml file?

Comment: According to YAML [reference](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html), a question mark is a key indicator when followed by a space (not sure what happens when **not** followed by a space, maybe it depends on your parser). You could try escaping it by putting it between double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I found a comment like yours 5 minutes ago. I tried and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key in a key value pair of a YAML mapping is, in "unabridged" YAML, introduced by a question mark. This allows parsing without lookahead (for the `:` following a key) and is sometimes necessary with complex keys (i.e. more than just a single string scalar), or if you want to have a key longer than 1024 characters, as that is the [restriction on lookahead](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2792501) for the `:`.

Your parser sees the '`?`', expects a key, but encounters a newline where it expects a key.

The normal solution to not have the parser interpreted the special characters (apart from `?`, also `&`, `*` and some others), is to quote them with single or double quotes:

```
folder:
  name: folderA
  files:
  - name: fileA
  folders:
  - name: '?'
    files:
    - name: fileB
```

You can count yourself lucky you wrote the file as you did. If you had put the question mark on its own line:

```
folders:
- name:
    ?
  files:
  - name: fileB
```

then the value for the key `name` would have been a mapping from null to null, as if you had written:

```
folders:
- name:
    null: null
  files:
  - name: fileB
```

and you might not have as easily noticed as with the error that you got, that that is not what wanted.